# C++ Why this doesn't cause redecleration error?

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace extra
{ int i; }//Declared an integer i here
    void i()
    {
       using namespace extra;
       int i; //We called namespace extra at above then we declared another i
       i=9;
       cout<<i;
    }
    int main()
    {

        enum letter{i,j};
        class i{letter j;};
        ::i();

        return 0;
    }
```

As I explained with the comments above we first declare an integer i at namespace extra then after calling it we declare another integer i then give it a value 9. My question is why this doesnt cause a redecleration error? Also at code line

```
i=9;
```

which i value gets the value 9 ? The one inside the namespace or the one inside the void i() function ?

NOTE: Please excuse my poor English.

Comment: `using namespace extra;` doesn't bring everything in from the namespace, it means "when looking for a name **also** look in that namespace". But as you have a local declaration of `i`, there is no need to look any further.

Comment: This is actually a good question, but not in the sense that it can receive a reasonable answer. C++ indeed has weird rules regarding identifies with the same name and shadowing. But it just happen to be designed this way. At least it is not as crazy as for example javascript can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the local one. As a rule of thumb, it is always the "closest" definition that is used.

```
struct A {};
int A = 0;
A b; // not ok, because A is the variable.
```

There is no error because there is no name `i` that denotes a variable in the global scope, or in the function.

A using directive just tells the compiler that if it can't find an appropriate name in the current context, it should also look in that namespace as well. In your case, the compiler didn't need to go into `extra` to look for a `i`, because it already found one in the function `i`.